# How a subspace of an affine set could be affine too?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In the book of Convex Optimization by Prof. Stephen Boyd in page 22, it can be seen that if $C$ is an affine set and $x \in C$, then the set:
$$
V=C-x_0=\{x-x_0|x\in C\}
$$
is a subspace. It can be simply prove that V is an affine set by formula as bellow:

If $v_1,v_2 \in V$ and $\theta \in R$ and considering this fact that $C$ is an affine set then the point $\theta(v_1+x_0)+(1-\theta)(v_2+x_0)$ lies in $C$ too. After some manipulation we have:

$$
\big(\theta(v_1)+(1-\theta)(v_2)+x_0 \big) \in C
$$

So, since $V=C-x_0$, then $\theta(v_1)+(1-\theta)(v_2) \in V$. So V is an affine set.

The question comes in mind when we imagine that we have the following image:

[an affine set $C$ and its subspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do4L4.png)

If you look at this picture and consider the definition of an affine set, the line through two points $v_1$ and $v_2$ lies in $V$ except in the point $x_0$. It is right that $x_0$ is not in $V$, but the whole of the line is not in $V$ so the subspace cannot be an affine set.

Could you please help in this issue. Thanks

Comment: Your picture is wrong. (1) $V$ does not lie in $C$, unless $0 \in C$, in which case $V = C$, (2) If that line is supposed to be in $V$, then the point you've labelled $x_0$ should be labeled $0$ instead. $x_0$ is somewhere else, actually inside $C$, and the correspoding line in $C$ has points $x_0 + v_1, x_0 + v_2$ on it, not $v_1, v_2$ themselves. An affine set is by definition the translation of some linear subspace by some fixed vector. $V$ is the linear space being translated, $x_0$ is the translation vector, and $C$ is the translated set.

Comment: Thank you Paul for your answer. As the book said and I mentioned here V∈C, so I think it does not matter that 0 be in C or not, V lies in C. Could you please explain more about your idea. Thanks.

Comment: It is not "my idea". It is the *definition* of what you are talking about. In your discussion of the problem, you *did not* say $V$ is contained in $C$, and I am absolutely sure your book didn't say anything like that either, because it is patently false unless $0 \in C$. That was an idea that you came up with on your own. Note that because $x_0 \in C, x_0 - x_0 \in C - x_0 = V$, so if $0 \notin C$, it is certainly not true that $V \subseteq C$, since it contains $0$ and $C$ does not.

Comment: Also, note that $\in$ means "is an element of", not "is a subset of". As $C$ is a set of vectors in some vector space, $V$ is also a set of vectors, not a vector itself, so "$V\in C$" is the wrong notation for what you are claiming.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected picture.

[image: C and V shown as separate parallel sets, with 0 in V where x0 is in C]

$V$ is a linear subspace, and $C$ is the translation of $V$ by $x_0$. Because $V$ is linear, any point in $C$ could be used as the translation vector. The result will be the same set $C$, no matter which is chosen.

$V$ is a translation of itself, by the vector $0$ (or any other vector in $V$). Thus $V$ is itself an affine set.